Does the SVG specification support advanced "mask" features?
I'm trying to get a firm grasp of exactly what is allowed in the "mask" presentation attribute in the SVG spec. The SVG spec just points to the CSS mask shorthand (https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#propdef-mask), which seems to potentially be a fairly complex attribute with a lot of variations. To help familiarize myself, I tried a number of experiments to see how some of these variations work, and quickly came to the conclusion that either I have no idea what I'm doing, or most of these options aren't supported by popular SVG renderers (Google Chrome, etc.).
Specifically I'm having trouble understanding how the "compositing-operator" flag is even relevant since as far as I can find, there's no way to actually make use of such an operator in the SVG standard. I'm starting to suspect that the SVG spec isn't actually intended to support the full CSS shorthand. All of the examples I've been able to find online have only ever had a URL reference to a mask element.
So, my question at this point is, is there any official guidance as to which features in the CSS masking module should actually be implemented by a conforming SVG implementer?

you'd need an SVG mask for compositing.

From the description, it sounds like the compositing-operator is intended for compositing between multiple mask layers. Is there a way to define a multi-layer mask that would be affected by this operator in SVG?

There are examples in the specification showing how it works.

There is no such thing as one multi-layer mask. Reference multiple sources (either images or SVG mask definitions) in mask-image, then mask-composite defines how they interact.

So, following the syntax from the CSS "mask" shorthand, would that be something like mask="url(#mask1) url(#mask2) subtract"?

It needs commas between the sources: url(#mask1) subtract, url(#mask2). Each layer defines the compositing with the one below

Thank you, I think that's the detail I was missing! Looking back at the spec, I see now that the syntax is #, and I must have overlooked the pound sign. If you write this in an answer, I will flag it as such.
